# mailto with HTML problems in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, html

Here I need to send one mail with `mailto(html)` or `mail_to(rails)` function. But the problem is with mail body, how to attach the body with mailto function, I mean , when I click on this  **Mail** link one Gmail client will open, so I need to get the **imageURL** in client body section.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var **imageURL**;
function code (email) {

   imageURL = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?
   chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=13&choe=UTF-
   8";
   $("#image_url").val(imageURL);
   $("#mailhere").html("<a class='btn btn-primary pull-left'
   href='mailto:"+email+"'>**Mail**</a>");
}


<div class="modal-footer" id="qr-code-footer">
 <a id="printme" href="#" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Print</a>
  <div id="mailhere" class="span1">
  </div>  
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`&body=Content`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto)

```
$("#mailhere").html("<a class='btn btn-primary pull-left' href='mailto:"+email+"&body=" + encodeURIComponent(imageURL) + "'>**Mail**</a>");
```

Comment: same happens all these vgrkrishnan@gmail.com&body=https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=59&choe=UTF-8 come to the "To" address bar.

But how to shows the body part in Body section of gmail client?

Comment: i have got it when i used like this href='mailto:"+email+"?subject=Qcode "+branch+"&body=Click here to get code "+encodeURIComponent(imageURL)+"'>Mail";